# Why must P be orthonormal, and not just orthogonal, for change of variable in Quadratic Form? [Kolman P560 8.8.24]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, quadratic-forms

Lay P402 : A change of variable is an equation of the form $x=Py$, 
where $P$ is an invertible matrix and $y$ is the (neW) coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ determined by the columns of $P$. (See Section 4.4.)

If this change of variable is made in a quadratic form $x^{T}Ax$, then
$ x^{T}Ax=(Py)^{T}A(Py)=y^{T}(P^{T}AP)y\ $
and the new matrix of the quadratic form is $P^{T}AP$. Since $A$ is symmetric, Theorem 2 guarantees there's an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{T}AP =$ a diagonal matrix $D$. This is the strategy of the next example.

> **My Question** $1.$  By virtue of Theorem 2, $P$ is orthogonal, but why must $P$ in fact be orthonormal? Lay doesn't reveal this, but the solution to the question below veraciously normalises the columns of P. If I kept $P$ as is (without normalising its columns), I wouldn't obtain the right answer?
>
> **Given Question :** Determine the standard form of the quadric surface $x^2 + y^2 -2z^2 + 2xy + 8xz + 8yz+ 3x +z = 0 \; (*)$.

Rewrite this as $x^T \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 4  \\
    1 & 1 & 4  \\
    4 & 4 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix} x
+ \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 1  \\
     \end{bmatrix} x = 0.$

Regarding the 3 by 3 symmetric A: $\lambda_1 = -6$ associates with $v_1 = (-1, 1, 2)^T$.  $\lambda_2 = 0$ associates with $v_2 = (-1, 1, 0)^T$.  $\lambda_3 = 6$ associates with $v_1 = (1, 1, 1)^T$.

P with normalised eigenvectors  $ = \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{6} } 
    \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ 2
   \end{bmatrix} 
   &
    \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{2} } 
    \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0
   \end{bmatrix} 
   & 
    \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{3} } 
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
   \end{bmatrix}   \\
    \end{bmatrix} $.

Define $y = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$. Apply the change of variable $x = Py$ to $(*)$:

$ y^T \begin{bmatrix}
    -6 &  & ~ \\
    ~  & 0 & ~ \\
    ~  & ~ & 6 \\
    \end{bmatrix} y + \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 1  \\
     \end{bmatrix} Py = 0 $. Now I complete the square.

$\implies -\color{orangered}{6}(x_2^2 + \dfrac{ -3 + \sqrt{2} }{\color{orangered}{6} \sqrt{6} }x_2 + \color{green}{\dfrac{ (2 - \sqrt{3} )^2 }{ 864 }}) +   
\color{orangered}{6}(z_2^2 + \dfrac{ 1 + \sqrt{18} }{\color{orangered}{6} \sqrt{3} }z_2 + \color{green}{\dfrac{ (1 + 3\sqrt{2} ) }{ 432 }} ) 
+ \dfrac{ -3 + \sqrt{2}  }{ 6 } y_2 = -6 \color{green}{\dfrac{ (2 - \sqrt{3} )^2 }{ 864 }} + 6\color{green}{\dfrac{ (1 + 3\sqrt{2} ) }{ 432 }} $.

This doesn't look right. The answer's $\dfrac{ x_3^2 }{ 1/2} - \dfrac{ y_3^2 }{ 1/2} = z_3$, a hyperboloic paraboloid.

**Supplementary:** I only lighted upon [P11 of this](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~len/LinAlg/chap3.pdf) afterwards; did I misconstrue 'orthogonal'?

> The terminology is very confusing. The deØnition of an orthogonal matrix
>   requires that the columns be mutually perpendicular and also that they be unit
>   vectors. Unfortunately, the terminology reminds us of the former condition but not
>   of the latter condition. It would have been better if such matrices had been named
>   `orthonormal' matrices rather than`orthogonal' matrices, but that is not how it
>   happened, and we don't have the option of changing the terminology at this late
>   date.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't study all details, but whether you use orthogonal or orthonormal coordinate changes, it doesn't change the fact that $P^T A P$ is diagonal.
(Note that an orthogonal matrix is usually defined as a matrix whose columns are **orthonormal**). Orthonormal coordinates are more intuitive; in an orthonormal basis, the equation of a circle still describes a circle (and not an ellipse), an ellipsoid has uniquely determined semi-principal axis by its equation, etc. If you just use orthogonal coordinates (i.e. transition matrices $P$ such that $P^T P$ is only regular and diagonal), you can no more distinguish a sphere and an ellipsoid (but you can still see the difference between a sphere and a hyperboloid, or a hyperboloid and a paraboloid).

The more general coordinate transformations you allow, the less details you see from the equation: if you consider the quadrics to live in a projective space and allow projective transformations, you can't even see the difference between the ellipse and hyperbole (but still can see the difference between that and a line) etc..